# Is Rip Hunter similar to the Doctor

Tags: dc, doctor-who, arrowverse, legends-of-tomorrow

Both Rip Hunter and The Doctor both are a time master and a time lord who both do the same thing

> Eve:a man who broke his oath, stole a timeship, and decided to change history for his own selfish reasons.

Both have time machines The Tardis and the Waverider and travel through time and space with companions of their own

so this made me think Is Rip Hunter similar to the Doctor ?

Comment: this question i asked i never thought of or even noticed

Comment: How haven't you already answered your own question by pointing out that they share similarities? What more are you looking for?

Comment: im just asking if they are similar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Not very

Although there are some similarities, there are also many differences. Many of them are enumerated [in this article](http://zap2it.com/2016/02/doctor-who-vs-rip-hunter-theyre-not-the-same/). For example:

- The Doctor is a technical pacifist who refuses to use guns and scorns military types, as seen in his attitude towards Danny Pink in Season 8.  Rip Hunter is not.
- The Doctor is an alien. Rip Hunter is not.
- The Doctor's time machine is an Eldritch Abomination in the shape of a police box. Rip Hunter's is not.
- Rip Hunter has a single, clearly-defined goal. The Doctor does not, besides generally helping people.
- At least in his original appearance, Rip Hunter invented his time machine. The Doctor did not.
- The Doctor can regenerate. Rip Hunter cannot.

What about the similarities you listed?

Well...

- In his original incarnation, Rip Hunter did *not* steal the timeship, but invented it, as previously noted.
- The Doctor is not trying to change history for his own selfish ends, and in fact tends to want to preserve it. Of course, it's not entirely certain that Hunter's reasons are selfish either.
- The Doctor did not break his oath when he stole the TARDIS, but long afterward.

Their main similarities are few, and mostly include traits common in science fiction, or indeed in real life:

- Both male (for now...), both travel through time, both good guys, both have certain disregard for the rules.